# Invocation of static methods in the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, methods, static

Why can't we have a static and instance method with the same name? How does Java handle a static method and how is the invocation of static methods determined by the JVM?

Comment: If they could have the same name, how would the compiler distinguish them?

Comment: They can as long as the signatures are different. :-)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `Class.method()` vs. `obj.method()`.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat A `static` method can be invoked from an object reference, so that would break.

Comment: One could add that the Java Virtual Machine is probably able to do this. It's the Java Language that does not allow this, due to the possible ambiguity.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, but I think that's where ZohebSiddiqui is getting confused.

Comment: @Marco13, The JVM is not able to do this as currently specified, and could not be modified to do this without breaking `Class.getDeclaredMethod`.  Please see my answer.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Just tested it, and you're right: It throws a `ClassFormatError` when trying to load the class with two methods with equal signatures.

Answer (score 2):

static keyword represent the class members.In a class there can be following class  members

1. static data members
2. static block
3. static methods.

Instance members represent attribute and behaviour of individual object whereas class member represents attribute behaviour of class.

Answer to your question ,it is not the case with static methods,any method u define whether it is static or instance ,u cannot initialize the another  method with same name. 
in java any static data  member and static method are loaded in class or method area.

After loading a class following instructions are performed

1. static data members (if define ) are created in class area.
2. static bloc (if define )is executed.

Any static data member or method(represents class behaviour) are invoked using name of class.

```
classname.Methodname(arguments if any)
```

class members are common to all objects hence they are available to objects of the class:the can be also invoked as:-

```
objectrefrence.methodname(arguments if any)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#34442) says

> ## 2.10.2 Method Signature
>
> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method and the number and type of formal parameters (§2.10.1) of the method. A class may not declare two methods with the same signature.

Note that modifiers (`public`, `static`, etc.) are not part of the signature used by the JVM to lookup a method.

There are distinct bytecode instructions for invoking `static` and non-`static` methods: [*invokestatic*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic) and [*invokevirtual*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) respectively, but both expect a method signature to identify the method to invoke.

It might be possible to change the bytecode specification so that *invokestatic* looks for a method with the given signature and with the `static` modifier, but that would require changing how Java reflection works, and break a lot of existing code.  It might also break new invocation mechanisms like [*invokedynamic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638735/whats-invokedynamic-and-how-do-i-use-it).