# What does Java's record equals() method actually do under the hood?

Tags: java, equals, record

In my Java code, I have a simple record class just like so:

```
record SingleIndexProperties<A>(A property) implements IndexProperties {

    // Here go implementations of IndexProperties methods; not relevant to question.

}
```

When I run a JMH benchmark of code using this record, I notice something interesting in the CPU time flame graph that is generated at the end:

[image: Flame graph showing what the equals() actually does.]

This is just an excerpt from a much larger flame graph of the benchmarked code. The interesting thing here is that, for some reason, the default `equals()` method of the record seems to be doing some dynamic calls.

Naively, I'd expect that the method would do something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (o instanceof SingleIndexProperties other)  {
         return Objects.equals(property, other.property);
     }
     return false;
}
```

Clearly, that is not the case. What does it actually do instead, and why? I looked for the source code, but I couldn't find anything.

(I'm on OpenJDK `Temurin-21.0.1+12`. The `Pair` you see in the flame graph is what is put into the record, and is itself also a record, whose `equals()` exhibits the same default behavior. Then inside the `Pair`, there are `Integer`s.)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043989/5133585) answer your question? This is another use of `invokedynamic`. It isn't really related to Java lambda expressions - the classes involved just happen to be called "lambda".

Comment: Considering that the overhead of it appears to be nearly 50 % of the run time of the `equals()` method, I'd like to understand what it's there for. Seems like writing a custom `equals()` for records to avoid this overhead would defeat the purpose of records.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický: Does your record just contain a `Pair<Integer, Integer>`? If so, then `equals()` should be extremely fast, so according to [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), I wouldn't expect that even doubling its runtime would impact the actual performance of your program.

Comment: In the benchmark above, I have found out that this single `equals` method makes up 2 % of my entire run time. In fact, the whole reason why I was benchmarking this was because I noticed a drop in performance after migrating some classes to records. This application is very performance-sensitive, single digits matter to me.

Comment: How many times are you calling `equals`? I would expect it to be slower when you only call it once or twice. It should be faster in the long run.

Comment: @Sweeper JMH shows 32 samples out of total ~3900. The code itself is on the hot path, so I would expect it to be called often.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what you are looking for in this question then? It is now clear that this is too slow for you, so you can just go back to implementing your own `equals`, and problem solved?

Comment: True. That said, I like to understand things - so I was hoping someone could tell me what it is that actually happens in there. Quick search for source code didn't turn up anything, but maybe I didn't look for the right thing in the right place. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Use `javap` to decompile the created java class, this will give you the source of the generated class file. That way you can see what is being generated for the `record` based `equals` method.

Comment: Does your benchmark have a reasonable number of warmup iterations before it starts sampling?

Comment: @M.Deinum Good idea; I should've thought of that.

Comment: @ruakh Indeed. My overall margin of error is well under 1 %.

Comment: It is not specified how `Record.equals` actually works; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#equals(java.lang.Object))