Understanding the difference between two Thread implementation approaches in Java?
I'm learning about Java Threads and I've encountered two different ways to create a thread. I'm not sure about the technical differences between them:
// Approach 1
Thread n = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100));

// Approach 2
Thread n = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100)::run);

Here's my complete example code for context:
public class NumberGenerator implements Runnable {
    private int limit;
    
    public NumberGenerator(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Which approach is better and why?
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100)::run);
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}


I've tested both approaches and they seem to work similarly, but I want to understand the underlying differences and best practices.
As fas as I know, both approaches use this constructor on Thread.java
    public Thread(Runnable target) {
        this(null, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
    }

So, can they be considered as subclasses of Runnable? What are the conditions to determine if an object is Runnable in this case? What are the technical differences between these two approaches?

1st uses the instance of NumberGenerator directly; 2nd creates a simple "function object"¹ that will call the run() method of the NumberGenerator instance. The 2nd one maybe a little bit more expensive, but it does not request the class to implement Runnable, that is, no need for a public accessible method ||| ¹ no additional (anonymous) class is needed, not the same

The second approach means you don't need to implement Runnable and can pass in reference to instance or static method of matching signature. Example new SomeClass()::anyVoidNoArgMethod or SomeClass:anyStaticVoidNoArgMethod

There is roughly no difference.
If you examine the bytecode (using javap -c Main):
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #7                  // class java/lang/Thread
       3: dup
       4: new           #9                  // class NumberGenerator
       7: dup
       8: bipush        100
      10: invokespecial #11                 // Method NumberGenerator."<init>":(I)V
      13: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
      16: astore_1
      17: new           #7                  // class java/lang/Thread
      20: dup
      21: new           #9                  // class NumberGenerator
      24: dup
      25: bipush        100
      27: invokespecial #11                 // Method NumberGenerator."<init>":(I)V
      30: invokedynamic #17,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:run:(LNumberGenerator;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
      35: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
      38: astore_2
      39: aload_1
      40: invokevirtual #21                 // Method java/lang/Thread.start:()V
      43: aload_2
      44: invokevirtual #21                 // Method java/lang/Thread.start:()V
      47: return

The only difference in between the two calls is that the second one involves invokedynamic.
It is not so easy to tell the difference but in the first case you gave the thread a Runnable so it will be bable to call its method run when appropriate (start), and in the second case you tell the thread that you explicitly want run to be called when it will call run at start. Nothing interesting here.
Since Java 8, you could use in place of an object that implements a run method, any object that has a method whose signature is the same by refering directly to this method:
class Test {
    public void myFunction() { // same signature as run
    }
}

...
Test test = new Test();
Thread t = new Thread(test::myFunction);
t.start();
}

This tells JVM to executes myFunction when start executes a call to run.
For more details, read about Functional Programming in Java.

You've just proven at the bytecode level that using a method reference in this case is redundant. That's exactly what I was talking about.

Thank you both for this interesting knowledge, @AndreySmelik. From my perspective, I find this explanation better.

Please add the command to view the bytecode

@AndreySmelik No you suggested that it creates a wrapper object, which is not the case I insist on this. There is no supplementary object involved.

@happy I added the command used.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès The InvokeDynamic #0:run:(LNumberGenerator;)Ljava/lang/Runnable; instruction tells the JVM to create an implementation of the Runnable interface using the passed NumberGenerator object.

@AndreySmelik Again no. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638735/whats-invokedynamic-and-how-do-i-use-it for example.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès LambdaMetafactory.metafactory() facilitates the creation of simple "function objects" that implement one or more interfaces by delegation to a provided MethodHandle, after appropriate type adaptation and partial evaluation of arguments.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès look at it from the other side; there is invokespecial #14 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V, an invocation of Thread’s constructor receiving a Runnable as an argument. Where does it come from if not from the preceding invokedynamic instruction? Or, to cite the specification: “At run time, evaluation of a method reference expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object.”

This code
Thread n = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100)::run);

the same as the following code
Thread n = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      new NumberGenerator(100).run();
   }
});

You are creating two Runnable objects, which is redundant.
It is less expensive and more logical to do it this way
Thread n = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100));


This is wrong. new NumberGenerator(100)::run is just a reference to a method of an existing object. No "secondary" object will be created.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès You are wrong. The Thread constructor requires an object that implements the Runnable interface. And in the new NumberGenerator(100)::run construct, the NumberGenerator class is not required to implement Runnable. So Java creates an object of an anonymous class that implements Runnable and passes it to the Thread constructor.

No. In that case java do not create an anonymous class. Method reference are not anonymous classes.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Strictly speaking yes, but this does not exclude the fact that in the second case two Runnable objects are created, versus one in the first case.

Sorry for that but you are wrong.

Your equivalent code creates the impression that new NumberGenerator(100) was evaluated each time, the run() method is invoked. But it is evaluated only once, before the second Runnable is created. It doesn’t matter much in this specific case, as the run() method will be invoked exactly once (and the reference is not null) but it’s better to be correct, to avoid confusion in other cases. For comparison What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println

@Holger How many times will new NumberGenerator() be evaluated in the code IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(i -> new Thread(new NumberGenerator(i)::run));?

As said, it’s special in that the run method will be invoked only once per thread. Hence, you still have one NumberGenerator instance per thread. But it’s important to keep in mind that it will make a difference in scenarios where you invoke the method more than once. For example IntStream.range(1, 100) .<Runnable>mapToObj(i -> new NumberGenerator(i)::run) .forEach(r -> { new Thread(r).run(); new Thread(r).run(); }); where two threads will share a number generator instead of creating their own.

@Holger Re. "two threads will share a number generator instead of creating their own" because you added r -> { new Thread(r).run(); new Thread(r).run(); }. How does this relate to how many times new NumberGenerator() will be evaluated in the expression IntStream.range(1, 100).<Runnable>mapToObj(i -> new NumberGenerator(i)::run))...?

Because, if you used .<Runnable>mapToObj(i -> () -> new NumberGenerator(i).run()) instead, the behavior would be different, i.e. each of the two threads would create its own number generator. That’s what I’m talking about all the time, the difference between creating one instance before the Runnable is created and reusing it on each run() invocation or creating a new one on each run() invocation. Your code sample suggests the latter but it’s wrong for this for of method references.

@Holger You can't use .<Runnable>mapToObj(i -> () -> new NumberGenerator(i).run()) because mapToObj() must receive an object of type IntFunction, but Runnable.run() does not return any value. So your claims do not make sense.

You could save so much time but just trying something before claiming that it won’t work. Then, use the saved time to understand what you’re seeing, i.e. an IntFunction producing a Runnable, ironically the same kind of construct used before, as i -> new NumberGenerator(i)::run also is an IntFunction producing a Runnable…

@Holger Okay, I was careless and made a mistake in saying that it wouldn't work. But the point is that you keep adding new inputs to prove your initially nonsensical statement about the number of times new NumberGenerator() is evaluated.  Did you count how many times the expression new NumberGenerator(i) will be executed you code?

What’s so hard to make a simple test, just fork the example and simplify it: https://ideone.com/iIky1W

@Holger You changed the input data again. So I repeat my question. How many times will new NumberGenerator() be evaluated in the code IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(i -> new Thread(new NumberGenerator(i)::run));?

I said numerous times that in this specific example, where the run() method is invoked exactly one time, it makes no difference. Still, the two code examples of your answer are provenly not equivalent. Making the simple fix to the second code example, to make it truly equivalent would have cost you far less time than this pointless discussion.

@Holger You said that "Your equivalent code creates the impression that new NumberGenerator(100) was evaluated each time, the run() method is invoked. But it is evaluated only once, before the second Runnable is created." I claim that the expression new NumberGenerator(100) is evaluated exactly as many times as the run() method of the anonymous class new Runnable() {} is called.

Yes, because that number happens to be one in this specific example. There is no worth in providing an answer on this site which is wrong but happens to appear to be right in one specific example. Readers will take that for granted and stumble over the difference in all other scenarios. I already provided this simplest example possible that demonstrates the fundamental difference.

@Holder The expression new NumberGenerator(100) in my code is executed exactly as many times as it is executed in Thread n = new Thread(new NumberGenerator(100)::run); not because it is a coincidence, but because it is intended that way.
